# jquery html net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Tags: jquery

I get this error in jQuery :

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

after using post method to execute the apache2 server in java.

```
$(document).on("click", "#restartServer", function() {
  $.post('/advyteam/ajax/admin/serverRestart',function() {})    
  $.done(function() {
    //do something
  })
  $.fail(function(){
    // do something when post failed 
  })
})
```

But the problem is when I do post it works right but I get the code in the `.fail` block that is not the case.

Comment: Looks like your server is not listening on `80`/`443` (and the ports are not filtered). Maybe it's busy restarting?